# How to find the IP of the DHCP server - Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

There seems to be some other DHCP server installing my linux machine on the same network .
How do I check the IP and remove the same ?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off your DHCP service, request a new IP address on a test machine configured to acquire a DHCP address, and check the network properties for that machine's LAN interface to see the issuing server.

How you remove it will depend on your environment.  You could unpatch the relevant network outlet, engage the rogue server owner's manager to apply policy, or speak politely to the person who may not realise what they are doing by plugging their home wireless router into the LAN...

Answer (score 0):

In the dhcp client configuration file you can specify to only allow dhcp updates from a certain IP address or only allow one class of IP addresses to be assigned.
But before doing this start the dhcpclient in the foreground and watch the monitor :) you will see the IP address of the rebel DHCP server.

Comment: Its a PXE boot , how can I start client ?

Comment: Mentioning this in the question would have been really, really and I mean really useful, I am not a fan of tagging.